# Unable to redirect SmartCard in Microsoft Remote Desktop for Mac. Option greyed out

Tags: macos, mac, remote-desktop, smart-card

I've been using Microsoft Remote Desktop for Mac to connect to a windows machine.

I used to be able to redirect a smart card to the remote windows computer. I recently upgraded the RDP app on Mac and now the option to redirect a smart card is greyed out. I've tried removing and re-adding the card but no luck. Has anyone seen this behavior before?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was addressed in version 10.6.3 of the Microsoft Remote Desktop for Mac.